# What can cause a node project to work on one machine but fail on another? (both are using the same versions of node)

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

In this case, we have 5 developer machines, and it's working on 3 and not on 2. All are pretty new macs.  All are using node 9.4 (via nvm.  Also I get the same error with node 10).

The main error we are getting when running `yarn start` is

```
.../server/start.js:74
    );
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

NOTE 1: The problem is related to trailing commas in babel
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas/
This comma is automatically inserted by Prettier, I believe!

NOTE 2: 
I found the problem is this yarn

```
=> which yarn
/Users/otto/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/shims/yarn
```

And when I run yarn in VScode, it works, because it's using a different yarn.

Comment: What's at line 74 of stat.js? can you show that code?

Comment: server.use(
      modRewrite(/* redacted */),
    );  <-- ERROR HERE

Comment: If you really have a comma after `modRewrite(/* redacted */)` of course that's a syntax error. I don't think this is anything other than user error. All of your other cases of errors are probably the same thing.

Comment: Hmm, it's because the comment got collapsed into one line, it's because trailing commas (I guess usually allowed by new babel syntax?) .  Maybe babel is not working right?

Comment: @Otto, was this ever resolved?  I am in similar situation.  4 different developer machines sharing the same project, but "yarn start" fails only on mine.